# Word tolerance of training phrases in Dialogflow (- to create a Google Action)

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, training-data, google-assistant-sdk, google-developers-console

I have an important question, at the moment i am writing my last essay before starting with my bachelor thesis. It is about voice apps, which includes the google actions for sure.

But i need some informations about the word tolerance of the training phrases. And I was not able to find some information on the internet yet. Does Google only recognize the training phrases typed in by the developer or can Google add some phrases by time or with training (so that the user can say different phrases to trigger an intent which were not typed in from the developer in the beginning) ?
It is really important for my essay. So I would be very happy if you can help me with this question.

I wish you a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow uses the [training phrases](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-training-phrases) to build a machine-learning algorithm to match similar phrases that aren't exactly what you enter.

> For example, the training phrase "I want pizza" trains your agent to recognize end-user expressions that are similar to that phrase, like "Get a pizza" or "Order pizza".

Comment: Ah thank you! Is it the same for Alexa and its Utterances ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how Alexa's platform manages training phrases and expansions.